# Simulink Coder - rtGetNaN() rtIsNaN()

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I have a really complicated SIMULINK model (that is why I don't want to post it here) and I would like to BUILD it (i.e. through CTRL+B shortcut). When I do I receive the following error. I know it is a lot of stuff, I don't want you to read all of it but I would like to know if someone of you had the same error or something similar and I would like to know, hopefully, how he/she solve it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Terminating Instance of rmsg_sub_TKState.
Terminating Instance of rmsg_pub_TKTrajectory.
Simulation Time: 0.000000
Real Time: 0.000000
Terminating Instance of rtblock.
### Invoking Target Language Compiler on simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.rtw
### Using System Target File: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/grt/grt.tlc
### Loading TLC function libraries
### Initial pass through model to cache user defined code
### Caching model source code
...............................................................................
........................................................................
### Writing source file simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp
### Writing header file simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_private.h
### Writing header file simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.h
### Writing header file simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_types.h
### Writing header file rtwtypes.h
### Writing header file builtin_typeid_types.h
### Writing header file multiword_types.h
### Writing header file rt_zcfcn.h
### Writing source file rt_zcfcn.cpp
### Writing header file rt_nonfinite.h
### Writing source file rt_nonfinite.cpp
### Writing header file rtmodel.h
### Writing source file simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_data.cpp
### Writing header file rt_sfcn_helper.h
### Writing source file rt_sfcn_helper.cpp
### TLC code generation complete.
### Using toolchain: GNU gcc/g++ v4.4.x | gmake (64-bit Linux)
### '/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.mk' is up to date
### Building 'simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/gmake -f simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.mk all
gcc -c -ansi -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fwrapv -fPIC -O0 -DMAT_FILE=1 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=1 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=0 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DTID01EQ=1 -DMODEL=simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr -DNUMST=2 -DNCSTATES=88 -DHAVESTDIO -DRT -DUSE_RTMODEL -DUNIX -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/BearingRigidity/BearingRigidity_DirConstr -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include/ros -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/matlab_ros_bridge/matlab_ros_bridge/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_traits/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/rostime/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/rosconsole/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/std_msgs/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/xmlrpcpp/include -I/usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/include -I/usr/include -o "rtGetInf.o" "rtGetInf.c"
gcc -c -ansi -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fwrapv -fPIC -O0 -DMAT_FILE=1 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=1 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=0 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DTID01EQ=1 -DMODEL=simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr -DNUMST=2 -DNCSTATES=88 -DHAVESTDIO -DRT -DUSE_RTMODEL -DUNIX -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/BearingRigidity/BearingRigidity_DirConstr -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include/ros -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/matlab_ros_bridge/matlab_ros_bridge/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_traits/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/rostime/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/rosconsole/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/std_msgs/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/xmlrpcpp/include -I/usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/include -I/usr/include -o "rtGetNaN.o" "rtGetNaN.c"
g++ -c -std=c++98 -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fwrapv -fPIC -O0 -DMAT_FILE=1 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=1 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=0 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DTID01EQ=1 -DMODEL=simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr -DNUMST=2 -DNCSTATES=88 -DHAVESTDIO -DRT -DUSE_RTMODEL -DUNIX -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/BearingRigidity/BearingRigidity_DirConstr -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include/ros -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/matlab_ros_bridge/matlab_ros_bridge/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_traits/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/rostime/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/rosconsole/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/std_msgs/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/xmlrpcpp/include -I/usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/include -I/usr/include -o "rt_nonfinite.o" "rt_nonfinite.cpp"
g++ -c -std=c++98 -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fwrapv -fPIC -O0 -DMAT_FILE=1 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=1 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=0 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DTID01EQ=1 -DMODEL=simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr -DNUMST=2 -DNCSTATES=88 -DHAVESTDIO -DRT -DUSE_RTMODEL -DUNIX -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/BearingRigidity/BearingRigidity_DirConstr -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include/ros -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/matlab_ros_bridge/matlab_ros_bridge/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_traits/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/rostime/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/rosconsole/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/std_msgs/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/xmlrpcpp/include -I/usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/include -I/usr/include -o "rt_sfcn_helper.o" "rt_sfcn_helper.cpp"
g++ -c -std=c++98 -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fwrapv -fPIC -O0 -DMAT_FILE=1 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=1 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=0 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DTID01EQ=1 -DMODEL=simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr -DNUMST=2 -DNCSTATES=88 -DHAVESTDIO -DRT -DUSE_RTMODEL -DUNIX -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/BearingRigidity/BearingRigidity_DirConstr -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include/ros -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/matlab_ros_bridge/matlab_ros_bridge/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_traits/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/rostime/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/rosconsole/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/std_msgs/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/xmlrpcpp/include -I/usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/include -I/usr/include -o "rt_zcfcn.o" "rt_zcfcn.cpp"
g++ -c -std=c++98 -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fwrapv -fPIC -O0 -DMAT_FILE=1 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=1 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=0 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DTID01EQ=1 -DMODEL=simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr -DNUMST=2 -DNCSTATES=88 -DHAVESTDIO -DRT -DUSE_RTMODEL -DUNIX -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/BearingRigidity/BearingRigidity_DirConstr -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include/ros -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/matlab_ros_bridge/matlab_ros_bridge/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_traits/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/rostime/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/rosconsole/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/std_msgs/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/xmlrpcpp/include -I/usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/include -I/usr/include -o "simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.o" "simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp"
In file included from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_types.h:32:0,
                 from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.h:31,
                 from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp:18:
/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/ESTIMATOR_sfcn_rtw/ESTIMATOR_sf_private.h:60:0: warning: "edges" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define edges(S)                       _ssGetSFcnParam(S,1)
 ^
In file included from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_types.h:26:0,
                 from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.h:31,
                 from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp:18:
/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/Bearing_sfcn_rtw/Bearing_sf_private.h:65:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define edges(S)                       _ssGetSFcnParam(S,6)
 ^
g++ -c -std=c++98 -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fwrapv -fPIC -O0 -DMAT_FILE=1 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=1 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=0 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DTID01EQ=1 -DMODEL=simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr -DNUMST=2 -DNCSTATES=88 -DHAVESTDIO -DRT -DUSE_RTMODEL -DUNIX -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/BearingRigidity/BearingRigidity_DirConstr -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include/ros -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/matlab_ros_bridge/matlab_ros_bridge/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_traits/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/rostime/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/rosconsole/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/std_msgs/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/xmlrpcpp/include -I/usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/include -I/usr/include -o "simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_data.o" "simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_data.cpp"
In file included from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_types.h:32:0,
                 from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.h:31,
                 from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_data.cpp:18:
/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/ESTIMATOR_sfcn_rtw/ESTIMATOR_sf_private.h:60:0: warning: "edges" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define edges(S)                       _ssGetSFcnParam(S,1)
 ^
In file included from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_types.h:26:0,
                 from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.h:31,
                 from simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_data.cpp:18:
/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/Bearing_sfcn_rtw/Bearing_sf_private.h:65:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define edges(S)                       _ssGetSFcnParam(S,6)
 ^
gcc -c -ansi -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fwrapv -fPIC -O0 -DMAT_FILE=1 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=1 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=0 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DTID01EQ=1 -DMODEL=simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr -DNUMST=2 -DNCSTATES=88 -DHAVESTDIO -DRT -DUSE_RTMODEL -DUNIX -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/BearingRigidity/BearingRigidity_DirConstr -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include/ros -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/matlab_ros_bridge/matlab_ros_bridge/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_traits/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/rostime/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/rosconsole/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/std_msgs/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/xmlrpcpp/include -I/usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/include -I/usr/include -o "rt_sim.o" "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src/rt_sim.c"
g++ -c -std=c++98 -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fwrapv -fPIC -O0 -DMAT_FILE=1 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=1 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=0 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DTID01EQ=1 -DMODEL=simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr -DNUMST=2 -DNCSTATES=88 -DHAVESTDIO -DRT -DUSE_RTMODEL -DUNIX -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab -I/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/BearingRigidity/BearingRigidity_DirConstr -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/devel/include/ros -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/matlab_ros_bridge/matlab_ros_bridge/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/roscpp_traits/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/roscpp_core/rostime/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/rosconsole/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/std_msgs/include -I/home/fschiano/ros_matlab_ws/src/ros_comm/xmlrpcpp/include -I/usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/include -I/usr/include -o "classic_main.o" "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/grt/classic_main.c"
In file included from /home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_types.h:32:0,
                 from /home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.h:31,
                 from /home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw/rtmodel.h:24,
                 from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/grt/classic_main.c:33:
/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/ESTIMATOR_sfcn_rtw/ESTIMATOR_sf_private.h:60:0: warning: "edges" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define edges(S)                       _ssGetSFcnParam(S,1)
 ^
In file included from /home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_types.h:26:0,
                 from /home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.h:31,
                 from /home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_grt_rtw/rtmodel.h:24,
                 from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/rtw/c/grt/classic_main.c:33:
/home/fschiano/Repositories/multiple_quadrotors/matlab/Bearing_sfcn_rtw/Bearing_sf_private.h:65:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define edges(S)                       _ssGetSFcnParam(S,6)
 ^
### Creating standalone executable ../simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr ...
g++ -Wl,-rpath,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64",-L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64" -o ../simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr rtGetInf.o rtGetNaN.o rt_nonfinite.o rt_sfcn_helper.o rt_zcfcn.o simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.o simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_data.o rt_matrx.o rt_printf.o rt_logging.o rt_sim.o classic_main.o rmsg_sub_TKState.o Bearing_sf.o rmsg_pub_TKTrajectory.o ESTIMATOR_sf.o rtblock.o /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so /usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/lib/libboost_signals.so /usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/lib/libboost_filesystem.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so /usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/lib/libboost_regex.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librostime.so /usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/lib/libboost_date_time.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libcpp_common.so /usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/lib/libboost_system.so /usr/local/boost/boost_1_49_0_gcc_4_7/lib/libboost_thread.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so -lm
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_thread.so.1.54.0, needed by /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so, may conflict with libboost_thread.so.1.49.0
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_regex.so.1.54.0, needed by /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so, may conflict with libboost_regex.so.1.49.0
rt_nonfinite.o: In function `rt_InitInfAndNaN':
rt_nonfinite.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `rtGetNaN()'
rt_nonfinite.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `rtGetNaNF()'
rt_nonfinite.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `rtGetInf()'
rt_nonfinite.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `rtGetInfF()'
rt_nonfinite.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `rtGetMinusInf()'
rt_nonfinite.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `rtGetMinusInfF()'
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.o: In function `simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr_eml_xgesvd(double const*, double*)':
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp:(.text+0x14ef): undefined reference to `rtIsNaN(double)'
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp:(.text+0x1546): undefined reference to `rtIsNaN(double)'
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp:(.text+0x15a1): undefined reference to `rtIsNaN(double)'
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp:(.text+0x1b74): undefined reference to `rtIsNaN(double)'
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp:(.text+0x1bc7): undefined reference to `rtIsNaN(double)'
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.o:simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp:(.text+0x2347): more undefined references to `rtIsNaN(double)' follow
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.o: In function `rt_atan2d_snf(double, double)':
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp:(.text+0x2396): undefined reference to `rtIsInf(double)'
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp:(.text+0x23ac): undefined reference to `rtIsInf(double)'
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.o: In function `simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr':
simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr.cpp:(.text+0x6a10): undefined reference to `rt_InitInfAndNaN(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake: *** [../simulationBearingRigidity_DirConstr] Error 1
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587228/undefined-reference-to-rtisnan?

Comment: It is curious that the first two compilation lines call `gcc` while the rest call `g++`. The two `gcc` lines are the ones that compile rtGetInf.c and rtGetNaN.c while the majority of the other files are C++ files. That could have something to do with it, or could be a red herring.

Comment: Are you using model references? You may need to double check your template makefile implementation (.tmf), especially the order of the libs in the linker. If your model references use blocks that require these rtGet* functions, but your top model doesn't, you may have issues...